# Atom linter does not work

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, lint

I am trying to install atom linter following this steps:

```
apm install linter
```

Then install this packages:

```
apm install linter-jshint
apm install linter-eslint
```

But I can't see the warning and the errors when I am using the editor.
What am I missing?

Comment: When you open a javascript file does your Atom know is a JS file? Bottom right of the application should read Javascript. If it says "Plain text" click and select "javascript". Then try to modify/save and it should work.

Comment: now it's working, but why it is not recognized as javascript file?

Comment: It needs to be in auto detect to do so.

Comment: It is on Auto detect but it recognized the files as: mongoDB(Javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom right of the application you should read Javascript. 
If it says "Plain text" click and select "Javascript". 
Then try to modify/save and it should work.

The linter just triggers if it's a javascript file.

[image]